# admin panel recent actions

Tags: django, history, action

I was wondering if I can get django admin (logged as super user) to display in some kind of "recent actions box", changes other users (non super users) made?

Thanx,

Luka

Answer (score 8):

LogEntry.objects.log_action()

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1052/

[Tying in to Django Admin's Model History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987669/tying-in-to-django-admins-model-history)

Answer (score 0):

it was my problem too, and it has a simple answer
Just go this address and do the following;
Address: `your virtulenv/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin`

And find ***base.html***, inside of this file edit after `{% load Log %}` and simply add this :

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
    {% get _admin_log (numbers of actions you want) as admin_log %}
```

And for the else do the same but at the end don't forget to add    `for_user` user

Comment: You should not edit this file directly, instead override it with a local version in your app/project. Also I currently show the location of get_admin_log as index.html instead of base.html.