# Using Django Admin History with a custom Login_backend and user model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a django application using a custom (ldap) login backend and my own extended user model that is used by other applications.

I'm using the django admin extensively but I've only just noticed that the history link leads to a yellow page. I realised that this was due to the fact that I was not using django.contrib.auth and so the auth_user table did not exist.
I uncommented that in my settings.py and the yellow screen is gone.

The history functionality is not working though and I'm guessing that's because the changes are stored against request.user but the lookup is searching for the user in auth_user.

Does anyone know how to make django admin use my user model table?

If not, does anyone have any idea how I could remove the history link from the admin object view?

Note: I'm looking for the solution with the least editing of the django source code as I will have to justify every line to my superiors.

Any help/suggestions/criticism would be very welcome

Thanks,

Hayden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define what is shown in the history of each model by [customizing the history view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.history_view), or you can simply remove the link from the admin site by [overriding the admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Either of these are recommended as they are upgrade friendly and don't involve any changes to the django codebase.

To use your custom model for the built-in history feature (and other related options) see the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987669/tying-in-to-django-admins-model-history).

Comment: Excellent response, thanks. I think I'll probably override the admin template for now, but I'll look into changing the history view as a phase two thing.