# Can a change to a model from the front-end reflect on the model (history) at the back-end in Django?

Tags: python, django, backend, web-frontend

I was just wondering, why? When I change a non staff user's name from the front end and post it, it doesn't record that action e.g Guest01 logs in and he updates his profile adding his first name and profile image. However it doesn't show in the history, yet I can see that the field has changed from the back-end.

Now as the admin I decide to remove the profile image of Guest01, change the first name and this time the action is recorded and goes into the history.

Now the question is can I make the change from the front-end reflect in the model history too or do I have to use a 3rd party Audit Trail which would mean redundancy of the history button for my model?

[image]

Comment: Your assumption that this history is only recorded when actions are performed from the admin app is correct.

Comment: @voodoo-burger is it possible to fix this

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987669/tying-in-to-django-admins-model-history

Comment: @itzmeontv done!! I also took my time to study the LogEntry and LogEntryManager then I got curious about the method in Model .save(update_fields=['anything']) could this be used from my views when saving a post to update the History or probably update a field in my model foreign to LogEntry? Well if that makes any sense it be an alternative perharps..