# How to update history record in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I got question about Django history. When I am in admin and change something in database, it will make an record in history of that object, that I made it or I update some record of that specific object.

When I paste the data to database through some form (when the user is log in), it will not make an record in history. I also tried to update value and it works fine but it will not make and record in history, that this and this was changed... Can someone help me how to do it please? What should I add to this part of code?

```py
t = Pool.objects.get(pk=Pools_id)
t.Status = "New"
t.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect('#')
```

Comment: You're using `django-simple-history` right? Could you show us your `Pool` model source code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tying in to Django Admin's Model History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987669/tying-in-to-django-admins-model-history)

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try that :)