# Foreign Key to two different Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

For my CRM I am trying to create an History model, that should store every change or action made on a specific Ticket (aka Customer Request).
In this scenario two type of users are involved: Resources and Customers.

Since both can make an action that should be stored in the History table (ex. Customers can open the ticket and Resources can close it)
I was wondering what is the right way to achieve this as a Foreign Key (`actor`)

```
class TicketHistory(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey("Tickets", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="ticket")
    action = models.ForeignKey("HistoryActions", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="action")
    resourceActor = models.ForeignKey("Resources", ...)
    customerActor = models.ForeignKey("CustomerUsers" ...)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As you can see I've initially decided to create two different fields, but I don't think it is the best solution.
How would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use:
https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Simple app - tracks all changes on an app/model

Answer (score 1):

You can use the admin site model log [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988202/6175325), or you can use `django-simple-history`. This last one make the same that admin site history log. Choose the one you like.